# Examples to show how to use Racket lexer generator?

Tags: scheme, racket, lexer

I am playing with the Racket recently, currently implementing a lexer for a subset of scripting language...and wondering whether there are more examples to show how to use the lexer generator in Racket?

I understand the calculator example in the doc, but it is too simple to show the full features...
I am especially curious how to reference position of each character....

Comment: Before answering this question: when you say "reference position of each character", you mean that you want a parsed representation that preserves information about the location of each token in the original source?

Answer (score 3):

The libraries at PLaneT are a great resource for more elaborate examples.
Try for example the [Infix Parser](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/soegaard/infix.plt/1/0/parser.ss) .